# Assert with googletest that a function does not return a value (void)

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I would have to test something like `EXPECT_EQ(MyFunction, void)`. I'd like to test this in a re-engineering project to ensure by Unit Tests that the new/reworked functions also does not return a value.

How can I do this with Googletest?

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++11 or later, you can use `decltype` to get the return type for a function, for example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

void MyFunction();

TEST(CheckApi, MyFunctionHasVoidReturnType)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE((std::is_same<decltype(MyFunction()), void>::value));
}
```